# Uniqueness of a field depending on another field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a scheme:

```
const tailSchema = new Schema(
  {
    personeFor: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      maxlength: 220,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    }
  },
  { versionKey: false, collection: "tails" }
);
```

The title field should be unique only in the aisles of the same value for the personeFor field.
That is, if personeFor: "firstPerson" I can specify the value of the title: "firstTitle" field - only once. But if the personeFor: "secondPerson" field - then again I can use title: "firstTitle". The uniqueness of the title should be in the forefront of one personeFor.
Is it possible to describe the scheme so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [unique compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index) to ensure that the tuple personFor/title is unique.

The mongo command :

```
db.tailSchema.createIndex(
    { personFor: 1, title : 1}, 
    { unique: true } 
)
```

Or in mongoose :

```
tailSchema.index({
 { personFor: 1, title : 1}, 
 { unique: true } 
);
```